# How to remove dupliate values from csv file whe 5 columns values 4 are same and one column values is diff

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv file as show in the blow format & I want to make changes as mentioned in the below sheet using python script so could you suggest me the respective methods to make it.

Sheet1:(input file)

```
Columns:   1     2     3     4    5
row1   :   abc   fff   v1    hhh  jjj
row2   :   abc   fff   v2    hhh  jjj
row3   :   efg   ooo   h1    ppp  www
row3   :   efg   ooo   h2    ppp  www
```

Sheet2:(out put file)

```
Columns:    1     2      3      4    5
row1   :   abc   fff   v1|v2   hhh  jjj
row2   :   efg   ooo   h1|h2   ppp  www
```

Could you please anyone help me to make it?

Answer (score 1):

To read `csv` and get it where you want you can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input_file_name.csv', header=None, sep='\s+')
#sep is the delimiter so change it if it is ',' for instance
#header is set to None as you seem not to have column names

df = df.groupby(['1', '2', '4', '5'])['3'].agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x)).reset_index()
df
#1     2     4    5   3
#abc   fff   hhh  jj  jv1|v2   
#efg   ooo   ppp  www h1|h2
```

Also, you can use `csv` module, but you'll see that `pandas` make it much easier:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as infile, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    value_place = 2
    result = {}
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        value = line[value_place]
        key = tuple(x for i, x in enumerate(line) if i != value_place)
        if key in result:
            result[key].append(value)
        else:
            result[key] = [value]
    desired = {k: '|'.join(v) for k, v in result.items()}
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for k, v in desired.items():
        writer.writerow(list(k)+[v])
```

Comment: Can we make it without pandas ?

Comment: Getting below error, could you check it ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 22, in <module>
    value = line[value_place]
IndexError: list index out of range
What does it mean by "k" & "v" ?

Comment: @MaheshAknur What is your delimiter?

Comment: Actually I have a CSV file which has huge data and every 2 lines are same, except 1 column value, as mentioned in the question, so my requirement it to merge all these common 2 lines(removing duplicates &  the respective value which is not same should be added with below line).

Comment: @MaheshAknur I understand that part, but what character separates the columns?

Comment: There is no character separates in the sheet as it's already separated.